# React lazy server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-ssr

I want to do server-side rendering with code splitting and the works. I'm using componentDidMount() to load data to be displayed.

Before delving into [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html), I would like to know how it would handle these situations (in case it has shortcomings). How does the ReactDOMServer determine when the page has finished loading, and render it to HTML? Will it render before my data has been loaded?

Comment: React DOM server runs before the page starts loading to generate the markup that will be sent to the clientside. Think of it as running all your component constructors and `render` functions once, but on the server (so no `window` object access or browser only APIs). Not sure if this is what you're asking though.

Comment: @apokryfos so if I'm using React.lazy, will it render before or after the component has loaded? or will my spinner be rendered to html?

Comment: [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) specifically says it has no ReactDom/server support right now

Comment: React.Lazy will only load your component in the memory only when it is required. Provided you have used code splitting wiht webpack.

Comment: @apokryfos I guess that answers my question ;)